# Can't get French accents to show for some error messages in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a site which is in two languages:  English and French.

There is a form. For some reason some of the error messages on the form display the French accents while other error messages will not. The pages are encoded in charset=utf-8.

Any ideas why this is happening and how I can fix this.  I have even encoded the translations using both the accent and the UTF coding set for the accents.

I get the following results:

which shoes the unicode characters instead of the accent they are supposed to show as in être

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have Rails 2.3.8. The problem is on the [translation_helper](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v2.3.8/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/translation_helper.rb) file that automatically encodes translations. To avoid this, you must append '_hmtl' or '.html' to the translation key or you can monkeypatch the translation helper.

More about Rails XSS protection: [Rails 3 Security Strategy](http://www.railsdispatch.com/posts/security) (that has also been backported to Rails 2.3.6+)

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I am a newbie so for me I am using yaml files for the translations. What is the translation key and where do I find it.  Or how can I monkeypatch my application and will this work when I put it up on someones server when the site goes live
Also I have a drop down menu with the countries populated in it. When I load the menu with the french words for the countries not using a key but loading directly from my database I see the UTF-8 codes for the accents and not the accents. Any ideasÉ